# Is it possible to enable javascript for a specific URL?

Tags: javascript, url, browser

There are many users who have JavaScript disabled and deny to enable it even for some business applications. Is there any way to allow a user to enable a JavaScript for a specific URL in order to use an application and then to disable again for the rest of URLs? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe. It depends on their browser. This isn't a programming problem though.

Comment: Do you mean you want to provide individual users with instructions to set their own browsers to allow JavaScript from a specific URL? That can be done in some (most?) browsers. In Chrome, for example, I think it's one of the advanced settings (Privacy / Content settings). If you mean that you want to somehow include some code on your web page to force the JS to be enabled you can't do that.

Comment: [This question at Super User](http://superuser.com/q/595839/151741).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can configure site zones. You could disable Javascript for all URL's in the main config, then enable it only for sites in the safe zone. You then add the white listed sites where you want JS to work to the safe zone. I'm afraid this only affects IE, though. Also, this kind of question is more suited to [Super User](http://www.superuser.com).

Comment: Apologies for my question which is not a programming problem indeed. I will ask the same question to Super User. Thank you Renan.